# Sql server migration assistant giving error while converting data from mysql to mssql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration, sql-server-2014

[image]

> Giving this error :    An unexpected error occurred. Please send the
>   log file to product support. For more information, see "Getting SSMA
>   Assistance" in the product documentation. The object reference is not
>   set to the instance of an object.

Comment: So, did you send the log file to product support?

Comment: No, i didnt but when i connect to mysql server first my tables are not loading.

Comment: Did you refer to the documentation as suggested in the error?

Comment: Yes, but i could not find anything